# Wanted to add cc recipients and multiple attachments with loop

Tags: excel, basic, vba

Sheet Name : EmailList

Basically I have 3 columns in sheet name as "EmailList".

In col. A there is a list of (ToRecipients), Col. B have a list of (CC Recipients) and col. C header as (fileBasename) have a list of files wanted to attached into an email.
I have code to add "ToRecipeints" but I need help to add "cc Recipients" and also attached each file into the mail mentioned into the each cell.

for eg : if i have 3 file name as 1. AP 2. TEL 3. J&K need to attach against the same "ToRecipients" and "CC Recipients".

## #ToRecipients#                       #|CC Recipients#     #|fileBasename|#

### abc@xyz.com;xyz.das@abc.com;         |a1234@xyz.com;       |AP,Tel,J&K  |

### a1234@xyz.com; xyz.das@abc.com;      |xyz.das@abc.com;    |Assam,JH,PB  |

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcessFiles()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


    Dim rowCount As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim fileName As String, emailTo As String

    With Worksheets("Email List")
        rowCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1))

        For i = 2 To rowCount
            emailTo = .Cells(i, 1)
            'If Left(filename, 0) <> "," Then filename = "," & filename
            fileName = getFileName(.Cells(i, 2))
            If Len(Dir(fileName)) Then SendMail emailTo, fileName, OutApp
        Next
    End With

    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
Public Function getFileName(filebasename As String)
    Dim folderPath As String, fileExtension As String, fileName As String, x As String

    folderPath = Range("Settings!B1")
    fileExtension = Range("Settings!B2")
    x = Range("EmailList!B1")

    If Left(fileExtension, 1) <> "." Then fileExtension = "." & fileExtension
    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
    If Right(x, 0) <> "," Then x = x & ","

    getFileName = folderPath & filebasename & fileExtension

End Function
Public Sub SendMail(emailTo As String, fileName As String, OutApp As Object)

    'Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    With OutMail


        .To = emailTo
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "Sales Forecast -" & " " & Format(Now, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
        '"Sales Forecast -  " & " " & Format(Now, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
        .body = "Dear " & "," & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine _
        & "Please find the attached file of Sales History of Last 6 Months" & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine _
        & "Requesting you to kindly provide the Retail Forecast for June 2018 at earliest by 27th of this month" & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine _
        & "Please feel free to contact if you have any questions regarding the same." & vbNewLine _
        & vbNewLine _
        & "Rgds" & vbNewLine _

         .Attachments.Add fileName
        .display
        'use.Send


        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing

       Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Rgds
Pankaj

Comment: Uhh, what exactly is your question? I'm looking at a wall of (not properly formatted) code only...

Comment: formatted my question. Please check and let me know if your are still have any queries.

Comment: Smells of VBA, not VB6.

Comment: @ Thomas..would you will be able to solve my problem..pls confirm

Comment: Can anybody Help with solution!!!